Failure to display information in the Access database in DataGridView
I created a connection with the Access database through an automatic call in DataGridView.  I did this because I needed to create a raw record in the datagridview by pressing a button and enter the information directly in the datagridview and save it in the database by pressing another button.  All the things I wanted are done, but my problem is that when I close the program and rent it again, it does not display the information stored in the database in the datagrid.  I don't know what the problem is.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Checker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet1.PersonChecker' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.personCheckerTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet1.PersonChecker);
           
            dataGridViewX1.Refresh();
            dataGridViewX1.ReadOnly = true;


            
        }

        private string convertmiladitoshamsi(DateTime miladidate)
        {
            PersianCalendar calendar = new PersianCalendar();
            return $"{calendar.GetYear(miladidate)}/{calendar.GetMonth(miladidate)}/{calendar.GetDayOfMonth(miladidate)} {calendar.GetHour(miladidate)}:{calendar.GetMinute(miladidate)}:{calendar.GetSecond(miladidate)}";
        }

        private void Btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            personCheckerBindingSource.AddNew();
            btnadd.Enabled = false;
            dataGridViewX1.ReadOnly = false;

        }

        private void Btncancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            personCheckerBindingSource.CancelEdit();
            btnadd.Enabled = true;
            dataGridViewX1.ReadOnly = true;

        }

       
        private void DataGridViewX1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridViewX1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                dataGridViewX1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
            }
        }
        private void DataGridViewX1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.RowIndex>=0 && e.ColumnIndex==6)
                {
                    DataGridViewCheckBoxCell checkBoxCell6 = (DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)dataGridViewX1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6];
                    DataGridViewTextBoxCell textBoxCell7 = (DataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridViewX1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7];
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(checkBoxCell6.Value) == true)
                    {
                        string persiandate = convertmiladitoshamsi(DateTime.Now);
                        textBoxCell7.Value = persiandate;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        textBoxCell7.Value = null;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void PanelEx1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Btnsave_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            personCheckerBindingSource.EndEdit();
            personCheckerTableAdapter.Update(database1DataSet1.PersonChecker);
            MessageBox.Show("آیا از درج اطلاعات مطمئن هستید؟");
            btnadd.Enabled = true;
            dataGridViewX1.ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
}

As I said, I expected to immediately see the information stored in the database in the datagridview after restarting the program, but nothing is displayed and the datagrid is completely empty.

The Copy to Output Directory build action of your database is probably set to Copy always instead of Copy if newer (or Do not copy, depending on how you're handling it, based on the final deployment strategy), so the updated database is overwritten each time you start the application

Yes.  When the program is run again, there is nothing in the datagrid, and when I create a new record and fill in the record, it replaces the previous records after saving.  Thank you for helping me improve my code
